# How to install diesel-cli with sqlite support under NixOS and cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, nixos, rust-diesel

When i try to install the diesel-cli with

```sh
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features sqlite
```

under NixOS, i get

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
...
 = note: /nix/store/kmqs0wll31ylwbqkpmlgbjrn6ny3myik-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

even though the Nix packages `sqlite` and `pkg-config` are installed. To me this looks like `sqlite` missing its static libraries, however i don't see any flag to enable in https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-21.05/pkgs/development/libraries/sqlite/default.nix.

Note:

1. Installing the `postgres` nix package and compiling the diesel-cli with

```sh
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

works flawlessly.

2. A workaround install the `diesel-cli` is using the Nix package of the same name https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-21.05/pkgs/development/tools/diesel-cli/default.nix which comes with enabled sqlite support. Nevertheless, i would like know how to compile it myself, and trying to compile the Rust project will fail with the same error above.

Comment: Do you have the nix `sqlite` package installed at all, either in the global environment or in the current shell?

Comment: Sorry, I did not noticed you have already noted that in your question. Please see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation seems to work using the following `shell.nix`:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [ cargo rustc pkg-config sqlite ];
}
```

If you only have `sqlite` and/or `pkg-config` installed globally instead, that might be what's causing problems. The `pkg-config` derivation sets some environment variables:

```
$ env | grep PKG_CONFIG
NIX_PKG_CONFIG_WRAPPER_TARGET_TARGET_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu=1
PKG_CONFIG_FOR_TARGET=pkg-config
```

and I do not think these are set if you use globally installed packages.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I extended the Nix documentation https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Rust and https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ/I_installed_a_library_but_my_compiler_is_not_finding_it._Why%3F